# Find the minimum number in a 2-d array with strings and numbers

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the minimum number that is assigned to string in a 2-d array using Python. I have been having some issues trying to build the array so my current solution looks like this:

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

array=['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
col = 2
row = len(array)
new_array= [[0] * col for _ in range(row)]
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(0, row):
    for j in range(0, col):
        new_value = randint(0, 9)
        new_array[i][j] = array[i]
        new_array[i][1] = new_value
print(array)
print(new_array)
```

`array[]` looks like this: `['abc', 'def', 'ghi']`

`new_array[][]` looks like this at the end of the loop:
 
    `[['abc',1], ['def',2], ['ghi',3]]`

What I need to know is the string that has the smaller number. 
I have tried importing `import numpy as np` and using  `print(new_array.min())`

I have updated my code. As of now, instead of using the random generator: 
I'm using a function that calculates the Levenshtein distance.

```
while j < len(T) 
    new_array= [[s, levenshtein_distance(T[j], input)] for s in T]
    if np.argmin(np.asarray(disT)[:,1]) > 
        levenshtein_distance(T[j], input):
        print('Minimum was already found in', new_array)
```

But the array is getting the same values for the distance (*I think is for how I'm assigning the values*):

```
[['abc', 2], ['def', 2], ['ghi', 2], ['jkl', 2], ['mno', 2], ['pqr', 2], ['stu', 2]
```

Comment: Can you provide a functional code? You did not precise what ```calculate_number``` does.

Comment: I have updated the code to assign a random number between 0 and 9. Thanks

Comment: When you say: "how to get the string with the minimum number (or numbers if there's more than one)." 

Are you saying that the array could look like [['string1', 1], ['string2', 2], ['string3', 3, 4, 0]] (and that in such a case, the correct string you want is 'string3')?

Comment: Yes @lampShadesDrifter there's the possibility that it will look like this: `[['abc', 2], ['def', 2], ['ghi', 2]] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `new_array` can be generated with one line of code using list comprehension:

```
new_array = [ [ s, randint(0, 9) ] for s in array ]
```

The correct function is not `np.min` that returns the minimum value of a list but `np.argmin` that returns its index (i.e. position):

```
idx = np.argmin(np.asarray(new_array)[:,1])
```

Knowing the position of the minimum value, you can retrieve the associated string:

```
print(new_array[idx][0])
```